# Upgrade to 2.3.5-p1 , module breaks bin/magento, how to disable?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have just upgraded my development environment to Magento 2.3.5-p1 using:

> composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5-p1
>   composer update

Running the **bin/magento** command line crashes on start with a fatal error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Cron\Model\DeadlockRetrierInterface in
>   /var/www/import/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:5

After some trial & error, I have managed to find the offending code (Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule:87) and the 3rd party module that triggered it.

How do I cleanly disable the module? I cannot run **bin/magento module:disable** as it won't even start.

Removing it from app/etc/config.php is not sufficient. If I move the module out of the way, and empty /generated/code, it stills triggers error about missing code.

> ```
> In ClassReader.php line 26:
>
>   Class Potato\Crawler\Model\Command\Queue does not exist
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find an answer, so I found another solution.

However, in this case, GIT to the rescue. I just reverted back and disabled the module in 2.3.4 instead. For production, I will need to do the same.

Comment: Next time if you want to disable module try not to remove entry from app/etc/config.php but change the value from 1 (active) to 0 (disabled) and after that run the bin/magento setup:upgrade command in cli.

Comment: @AdamS. The problem was in being unable to run bin/magento. After the upgrade it died before it could anything, the problem being the automatic code generator throwing an exception.